# Angular BehaviorSubject - how to remove all data?

Tags: angular, observable

I'm not traditionally a UI developer, and I still haven't wrapped my head around `BehaviorSubject`. We have an ErrorNotificationService. When an error occurs on a page, we push the error onto `addError`. When the error is dismissed, we remove it from either `removeErrorById`, or `removeErrorByIdentity`.

I'm pushing errors to a BehaviorSubject, and when I navigate from the page, I want to remove all errors it's holding. The code currently looks like this:

```
export class ErrorNotificationService {
  public addError: BehaviorSubject<ErrorNotification> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  public removeErrorById: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  public removeErrorById: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  public createNotification(pid: string,
                            message: string,
                            key: string,
                            displayContact: boolean,
                            errorCode: string = null): void {
    this.addError.next(new ErrorNotification(pid, message, displayContact, errorCode, key));
  }

  public dismissNotification(pid: string, key: string): void {
    this.removeErrorByIdentity.next(`${pid}_${key}`);
  }

  public dismissAllNotifications(pid: string): void {
    this.removeErrorById.next(pid);
  }
}
```

This is how we subscribe to the `BehaviorSubject`(s):

```
  private subscribeToErrorService(): void {
    this.errorService.addError.subscribe(
      (error) => {
        this.addNewError(error);
      }
    );
    this.errorService.removeErrorById.subscribe(
      (id) => {
        this.deleteErrorById(id);
      }
    );
    this.errorService.removeErrorByIdentity.subscribe(
      (identity) => {
        this.deleteErrorByIdentity(identity);
      }
    );
  }
```

And here's the component code that tracks the errors:

```
  public currentErrors: ErrorNotification[] = [];

  public deleteErrorById(id: string): void {
    if (id !== null) {
      this.currentErrors = this.currentErrors.filter( (error) => error.getId() !== id);
    }
  }

  public deleteErrorByIdentity(identity: string): void {
    if (identity !== null) {
      this.currentErrors = this.currentErrors.filter( (error) => error.getIdentity() !== identity);
    }
  }

  private addNewError(error: ErrorNotification): void {
    if (error !== null) {
      this.currentErrors.push(error);
    }
  }
```

The `delete...` and `add...` methods remove/add from an array holding the errors. I have an `ngOnDestroy()` method that I want to clear all errors created by that page (the pid). The problem is, when there's more than one error, we seem to only pop the first one from the `BehaviorSubject`. `dismissAllNotifications` isn't behaving as expected. I can't seem to come up with a way to iterate through `removeErrorById` to get rid of all the errors.

I hope this makes sense. I'm still trying to understand this code myself, so I don't know if my problem is clear. In fact, I don't even know for sure that this design works as intended! Thanks for any help.

P.S. - If I'm going to be down-voted, it would be great if someone could tell me why...

Comment: We need more context here.  Your ErrorNotificationService doesn't appear to be keeping a full list of the current errors.  It appears that your methods that interact with your service must be (i.e.e addNewError, deleteErrorById).  Those methods would be helpful.

Comment: Specifically what would be helpful is to see the method you expect to be called when dismissAllNotifications is called.  Which I guess is deleteErrorById?

Comment: @KyleAnderson, I really appreciate your response. I've added those methods.

Comment: So you ngOnDestroy method that is trying to remove everything is in the same location (component?) as your currentErrors array?  Or are they in different locations?  Your ngOnDestroy method might be useful as well (working or not) to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, `ngOnDestroy` just invokes `dismissAllNotifications`. That's the only line in it. I want to remove all errors that page pushed to the `currentErrors` array, as indexed by the UUID created in the page's constructor.

Comment: Ok, sorry I don't think I can help you.  Everything I can see looks good.  Have you tried putting a break point on this line to see what actually happens?        'this.currentErrors = this.currentErrors.filter( (error) => error.getId() !== id);'

Comment: @KyleAnderson, I'll do that. Thanks for your input!!